# How do I print a "Protected" return value? (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, google-ads-api, protected

I'm working with the Google AdWords API in order to obtain costs-per-click (CPC) data for given keywords. When I run this code:

```
$averageCPC = $data[AttributeType::AVERAGE_CPC]->getValue();
print_r($averageCPC);
```

I see the following:

```
Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201702\cm\Money Object
(
    [microAmount:protected] => 754133
    [ComparableValueType:protected] => 
    [ComparableValue.Type] => Money
)
```

How can I print just the number 754133?

Comment: Try casting it to a string

Comment: The `Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201702\cm\Money` class probably has a method to get the `microAmount` since it's protected. You're not meant to be getting it, so you must be doing something wrong if there's no method to get it. **Edit: [as I said, there's a method - use it instead of accessing the value directly.`$averageCPC->getMicroAmount()`](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/master/src/Google/AdsApi/AdWords/v201702/cm/Money.php#L30)**

Comment: You find the method that returns that value and use it.

Comment: Have you tried $averageCPC->getMicroAmount()? (it`s just guess).

Comment: Great, thanks @h2ooooooo, $averageCPC = $averageCPC->getMicroAmount(); worked. Good job finding the class.

Comment: @SteveBecerra No problem - glad it worked. For reference if you have a class like `Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201702\cm\Money` you can usually find the source by googling the namespace (`Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201702\cm`) followed by the class name (`Money`) with both in quotes: `"Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201702\cm" "class Money"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to not make this go unanswered. Usually if a variable is protected it's because you're not supposed to be getting it (at least not without using a method that *could* do other things than just returning the variable value - this gives a lot of flexibility for the developers to add code without changing all the places that get the variable which they can't in this case as google doesn't control your code).

That said, [the Money class can be found here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/master/src/Google/AdsApi/AdWords/v201702/cm/Money.php#L30).

As you can see there's a method for getting the value with the access of *public* so you *are* allowed (and very likely recommended) to call that and it simply returns the value:

```
/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getMicroAmount()
{
  return $this->microAmount;
}
```

Hence the answer is fairly simple; call the method.

```
$averageCPC = $data[AttributeType::AVERAGE_CPC]->getValue();

$microAmount = $averageCPC->getMicroAmount();

print_r($averageCPC);
var_dump($microAmount); // int(754133)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `ReflectionClass`

```
function accessProtected($obj, $prop) {
 $reflection = new ReflectionClass($obj);
 $property = $reflection->getProperty($prop);
 $property->setAccessible(true);
 return $property->getValue($obj);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but @h2ooooooo was able to find the actual Money class and there is already a function there called  getMicroAmount() that returns the value.